# How to decrease the delay on starting CSS animations/transitions in Android WebView?

Tags: webview, android-webview, delay, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to use CSS3 animations in Android WebView but I'm getting a very annoying delay when starting the animation (roughly 500ms).

The animation runs smoothly, no lag, but it has the delay at start. Since there is no lag, I assume that's not a performance issue. Or it could be?

It's not the default 300ms onclick delay, I've already changed to ontouchstart and when I do anything else than animations/transitions, there is no delay. Only with these two.

It's not the animation-delay property as well, I've already set it to 0.

Any possible explanation/solution?

PS: The animation/transition I'm trying to run is with `transform: translateX()` property. Before, I was trying with `left: Xpx`, but it was lagging during the animation. With transform, there is no lag, but there is the delay.

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: No, I'm not using any framework, just pure HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Bump. I'm seeing crazy long delays on an iPad 2 running an older iOS version. It seems to be calculating the transforms for several dozen elements before it begins. It then runs very smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and failed to find a reasonable solution. I've tried different approches and these are my conclusions:

- making animation longer makes it look more smooth, but doesn't reduce the delay at the beginning
- turning hardware acceleration OFF makes animation faster (delay is also reduced) but some frames are being dropped and animation isn't smooth anymore
- changing all `translate3d` to `translateX`/`translateY`/`translateZ` - no visual difference
- changing animation into multiple transitions controlled via JavaScript (`transitionEnd` event) makes it slower with multiple hiccups on the way (each time when `transitionEnd` is fired).

My guess is that CSS animations are just slow on Android and require some pre-computation to display them; hence the delay at the beginning. We'll probably need to wait for Chrome to became the default browser for Android.

Comment: As much as I hate to admit it, because supporting old devices and Android versions is still a requirement for most developers, we might just need to go back to JavaScript animations, hoping for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it would help with the delay, but perhaps you should use `translate3d(x,0,0)` instead of `translateX`, because 3D transformation run on hardware.

I can't find the reference for that now, but I remember reading an article about it in the Google Android HTML Developers site.

Comment: Are you sure that only `translate3d` gets accelerated? I think that whole family of `translate` functions is accelerated. Anyway, this is not a good solution for this problem - I've tried both `translate3d` and `translateX` and found no visible difference.

Comment: Well, if you said you saw no visible difference than I guess my suggestion is not the solution to your problem. About if only `translate3d` is accelerated, than that is what I read in several places, including Google's explanations of correct, faster CSS. It was weird for me as well, and perhaps it was changed in later versions of Chrome, and I can't be sure it is so in all browsers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issues on stock browser.  Turns out that you can add this to the block you're animating:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

This should smooth out the animations, making them start sooner and also removing a flicker before and after the animation.